# How do I preload my cloud save?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

1. I have a cloud save for an Xbox One game but no copy of the game here. I plan to bring my Xbox One somewhere without Internet (offline) to play it. How can I preload my cloud save before the Xbox One has a local copy of the game?
2. I want to check whether I have a cloud version of a save on my account before I purchase a game.

How can I see what game saves are attached to my Xbox Live cloud account? How can I preload them to my Xbox One?

Comment: Dont want to answer without knowing the right procedure, but you should be able to access your save data on the cloud in a similar fashion to how you would look at your save data in the harddrive. There should also be a means to look at all save data for a game, and opt to look at the cloud, but I am unsure if you can do this without actually having the game installed.